# How to add coupon list to WooCommerce product page like AliExpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WordPress (5.3.2) with WooCommerce (3.9.1) and I would like to add a discount coupon list dropdown in single product pages. I've been looking at all Woocommerce templates, but I cannot find a way to add the Woocommerce coupon field onto the product page.

Any ideas?

Please also suggest exact plugin that works.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try use this snippet in your product page:

```
$args = [
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'orderby'          => 'title',
    'post_type'        => 'shop_coupon',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
];

$coupons = get_posts( $args );
```

Or add to function.php:

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', function () {
    $args = [
        'posts_per_page'   => -1,
        'orderby'          => 'title',
        'post_type'        => 'shop_coupon',
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
    ];
    $coupons = get_posts( $args );
    //some logic
});
```